# Read text file of protein sequences in python

Tags: python

I am trying to read DNA Sequences in Pandas Data frame but not getting the whole sequence in Data frame column.

I have tried File.open method simple read_csv method these methods didn't help me much.

```
pd.read_csv('../input/data 1/non-cpp.txt', index_col=0, header=None)

Output:

0
>
GNNRPVYIPQPRPPHPRI
>
HGVSGHGQHGVHG
>

myfile = open("../input/data 1/non-cpp.txt")
for line in myfile:
    print(line)
myfile.close()

>

GNNRPVYIPQPRPPHPRI

>

HGVSGHGQHGVHG

>

QRFSQPTFKLPQGRLTLSRKF

>

FLPVLAGIAAKVVPALFCKITKKC
```

[DataSet Source](https://www.kaggle.com/sohaibanwaar1203/protein-sequences)

[image: Here are some of sequences I want to read]

- Label of Sequence
- long Sequence (String)

I need labels in one column which you can see in 1st and whole sequence in the second column which you can see in second row e.g

Label

[image]

Sequence

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide an excerpt of the file you want to read from?

Comment: its a notpad file .. with .txt extension

Comment: So you want a single sequence out of one file? That is, concatenate all lines into one long line?

Comment: @Prune Sorry I am feeling difficulty in understanding the problem. I have added more information will you please help me out, Thanks

Comment: What goal do you want to achieve? What do you want to get from that file and what kind of data structure do you want to use?

Comment: We'll be happy to help once you can define your problem.  Again, refer to the posting guidelines.

Comment: Sir I need to get lables in one coloum and all the sequence in the second coloum. Sorry for the less information I will edit and add this @sentence

Comment: I am Trying my best Sir! To define my problem as much as I can Sorry for the inconvenience. @Prune

Comment: What is the number of lines in the image you posted? 4 or 8? What is _Label of Sequence_? Please, provide an example of the result you want to achieve. Moreover, it is hugely better you provide an excerpt of the file as text rather than as an image.

Comment: thank you so much @sentence  for helping me out. Really like stack overflow community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a rough not one liner but it will give you what you need, a series with the DNA sequences.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('cpp.txt', sep=">",header=None)

data[0].dropna()
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your file is something like:

```
>a1|b1|c1
a111
>a2|b2|c2
a222
>a3|b3|c3
a333
```

Note that here we have 6 lines.

Then, you can read the file, and store the data:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

n = len(content)

label = [content[i].strip() for i in range(0,n,2)]
seq = [content[i].strip() for i in range(1,n,2)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'label':label,
                   'sequence':seq})
```

and you get a pandas dataframe:

```
      label sequence
0   >a1|b1|c1   a111
1   >a2|b2|c2   a222
2   >a3|b3|c3   a333
```